# Paypal adaptive payment method for Paypal account verification

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Any one can help for Paypal adaptive payment method for Paypal account verification. When we go to live mode and generate Live APP Id it is showing error:

```
{
    "responseEnvelope": {
        "timestamp": "2015-09-18T02:23:23.202-07:00",
        "ack": "Failure",
        "correlationId": "4321940d358d5",
        "build": "18018453"
    },
    "error": [
        {
            "errorId": "560022",
            "domain": "PLATFORM",
            "subdomain": "Application",
            "severity": "Error",
            "category": "Application",
            "message": "The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value",
            "parameter": [
                "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found answer of Paypal adaptive payment and check paypal valid email or not. 
When create an App, need to fill complete information of APP and if you want to check only Paypal email exist or not. Deselect 'Chained Payments' within your App Submission.

Paypal can allow you to use GrtVerifiedStatus. However, please ensure to set the 'matchCriteria' parameter to 'NAME' as the permission to use 'NONE' is highly restricted.